# Rails 404 redirect method affecting controller actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails application where I redirect to a 404 page if the user types in a url that does not exist. I did this because my logs shows someone trying to find a loophole in my coding to attack the website. Unfortunately the code that forces the redirect is affecting the app where I cannot subscribe individuals to a list. This is my application_controller.rb file.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_filter :verified_request?
  $attack_attempts = 0



  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :not_found 
  rescue_from Exception, with: :not_found
  rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, with: :not_found


  def verified_request?
    if request.content_type == "application/json"
      true
    else
      super()
    end
  end   


  def raise_not_found     
     raise ActionController::RoutingError.new("No route matches # {params[:unmatched_route]}")
  end

 private

  def not_found
    $attack_attempts+=1
    if($attack_attempts >=5)
        flash[:alert] = ' Your attempt to hack this website has been recorded. Stop doing this, or else you would be fined. You wont like it.'
    end  
    respond_to do |format|
       format.html { render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404", :layout => false, :status => :not_found }
       format.xml { head :not_found }
       format.any { head :not_found }
    end
  end
  def error
     respond_to do |format|
         format.html { render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/500", :layout => false, :status => :error }
         format.xml { head :not_found }
         format.any { head :not_found }
     end
  end   
end
```

I have this line of code in my routes.rb file:

`get '*unmatched_route', to: 'application#raise_not_found'`

And then this is the output my shell gives me:

```
Started POST "/subscribe" for ::1 at 2015-11-13 16:10:52 -0700
Started POST "/subscribe" for ::1 at 2015-11-13 16:10:52 -0700
Processing by OpenhwyController#subscribe as HTML
Processing by OpenhwyController#subscribe as HTML
Parameters:   {"authenticity_token"=>"pE3nXohfktO/oyHH7d0C/5Z3REHPgjuJuFTTMxdmv1Dzx+jE5hBfR1b0S0PDec+OORbQA29yEvzJTw3J8zgOAg==", "first_name"=>"wfrwfrw", "last_name"=>"fwrfwfw", "email"=>"wrwfwfr"}
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"pE3nXohfktO/oyHH7d0C/5Z3REHPgjuJuFTTMxdmv1Dzx+jE5hBfR1b0S0PDec+OORbQA29yEvzJTw3J8zgOAg==", "first_name"=>"wfrwfrw", "last_name"=>"fwrfwfw", "email"=>"wrwfwfr"}
Rendered public/404.html.erb (0.7ms)
Rendered public/404.html.erb (0.7ms)
Completed 404 Not Found in 7ms (Views: 4.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 404 Not Found in 7ms (Views: 4.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
source=rack-timeout id=eded6b111d5138a15736722031037e4c timeout=15000ms       service=14ms state=completed
source=rack-timeout id=eded6b111d5138a15736722031037e4c timeout=15000ms service=14ms state=completed
```

For further reference sake this is the action if fails to execute:

```
def subscribe
    begin
    gb = Gibbon::Request.new
    list_id = "********" list id hidden for security sake.
    subscribe = gb.lists(list_id).members.create(body: {email_address: params[:email], status: "subscribed", merge_fields: {FNAME: params[:first_name], LNAME: params[:last_name]}})
        if subscribe
            redirect_to :back, notice: " Congrats You'll be notified as soon as we go live!!"
        end
    rescue Gibbon::MailChimpError => e
        redirect_to :back, alert: " Please fill out all fields with the required info to subscribe, emails in this format:abcd..1234@youremailprovider.youremailprovider'sdomain" 
    end 
end
```

As @jvnill asked. I am adding the routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'openhwy#coming_soon'

  post 'subscribe', to: 'openhwy#subscribe'

  get 'about_us', to: 'openhwy#about_us'

  get 'pricing_page', to: 'openhwy#pricing_page'

  get 'contact/send_contact_request'

  post 'contact', to: 'openhwy#contact'

  get '*unmatched_route', to: 'application#raise_not_found'

end
```

**Answer:**

Thanks to @jvnill and @marek for their contributions. The error was with this line:

```
rescue_from Exception, with: :not_found
```

This forced the 404 page anytime there was an error even of it dod not pertain to the action.

Comment: did you place the catch all route to the bottom of your routes file?

Comment: yes I did. i would update the question with the routes file. @jvnill

Comment: ah my bad.  from the logs, the request doesn't go through the catch all route.  it still goes to the `subscribe` action.  I think the issue is with `gb.lists(list_id)`.  If you're using `.find` in the lists method, and the id you pass is not in the database, then you'll get a 404 in production.

Comment: @jvnill The moment I remove the error methods. It works fine. In development, I don't set an api key and that's the error I get when the custom 404 redirect methods are not there. The moment I add them back, this happens.

Comment: another cause may be because of the `redirect_to :back` call you have there.  From the docs `When using redirect_to :back, if there is no referrer, ActionController::RedirectBackError will be raised. You may specify some fallback behavior for this case by rescuing ActionController::RedirectBackError.`

Comment: @jvnill Impressive observation. This is my first time learning about this ActionController::RedirectBackError. Let me make adjustments and get back to you with updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the feeling you are getting some exception in your subscribe controller action and because of the line:

```
rescue_from Exception, with: :not_found
```

in ApplicationController your application is rendering 404...

Marek

Comment: I removed that and it works in development. I would switch to production to see if it works. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: oh nice! +1 I didn't see that.